# _ManageNav doesn't work after add my own Identity class

Tags: c#, .net-core, identity

I used Identity in .NET Core 2.1. MVC app and I have one problem. As long as I used build-in class IdentityUser, my _ManageNav works good: when I clicked on UserName, on the left side of my application I saw ManageNav menu. But I must implicate my own class, because I must have list for users:

```
public class MyAppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
}
```

Of course I change in Startup information about class:

```
services.AddIdentity<MyAppUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Also add a mail sender, because I had error with this:

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, MyAppMailSender>();
```

My _ManaveNav is practically build-in, I didn't have to change anything because first I wanted configure my own class, this is my _ManageNav:

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@{
    var hasExternalLogins = (await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).Any();
}
<div class="menu-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="@ManageNavPages.IndexNavClass(ViewContext)"><a asp-page="./Index">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="@ManageNavPages.ChangePasswordNavClass(ViewContext)"><a id="change-password" asp-page="./ChangePassword">Password</a></li>
        @if (hasExternalLogins)
        {
            <li class="@ManageNavPages.ExternalLoginsNavClass(ViewContext)"><a id="external-login" asp-page="./ExternalLogins">External logins</a></li>
        }
        <li class="@ManageNavPages.TwoFactorAuthenticationNavClass(ViewContext)"><a asp-page="./TwoFactorAuthentication">Two-factor authentication</a></li>
        <li class="@ManageNavPages.PersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext)"><a asp-page="./PersonalData">Personal data</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried with IdentityUser or MyAppUser in first line (@inject), but always I have default menu, which I have normal in app. My Identity layout:

```
@{
Layout = "/Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml"; }

<h2>Manage your account</h2>
<partial name="_MenuTop" />
<div class="all">

    <partial name="_ManageNav" />
    <div class="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <partial name="_MenuRight" />
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
}
```

Maybe one of You have this problem in Your app? I think ManageNav and Layout is OK, because on version where I use IdentityUser ManageNav works great.

Best regards,
Kamil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you should use your custom class here:

```
@inject SignInManager<MyAppUser> SignInManager
```

instead of:

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
```

Comment: Hello Dmitry! Thanks for reply. I tried this, but effect is the same. I don't see a ManageNav.

Comment: @KamilM check this https://www.coderepo.blog/posts/building-elegant-applications-aspnet-core-mvc-2.1-coreui-2-bootstrap-4/#4-3-customize-identity-views and that https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview2-now-available/#user-content-customize-default-identity-ui

Comment: This partially worked.  I also had to add the namespace for my identity user to the razor and the MVC _ViewImports.cshtml files.   But big time thanks for getting me on the right track!

Comment: Make sure you have updated code to custom user / role types in your scaffolded views/pages for Identity (those are under Accounts area / folder)

Comment: @wondernate
Excellent suggestion. I've just added my namespace in the _ViewImports files and the _ManageNav found the new ApplicationUser.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `_ViewStart.cshtml` file in the `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage` folder with the following content:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect this to solve the problem? They're already explicitly referencing their layout in their view.

Answer (score 0):

Read this

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/8440

If you have your views in the "Views" folder then when applying the fix provided by @rjax be sure to change the path from Layout = "/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; to Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";. With this in place everything worked perfectly for my team.

[image]